# Spritekit multiple device resolution detection

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, resolutions

I have backgrounds for iPhone 4s, 5, 6, 6plus, iPad, iPad retina.  My question is how to distinguish them from each other since many are retina(@2x).  Can I use the same filename for the background and add @2x, @3x?  It seems to pick up the wrong backgrounds from the @2x ones when I do this(i,.e iPhone 5 on a iPad Retina). There must be an easier way then checking every single resolution and pulling that image.  Clarity on this would be very helpful thanks!

In the scene itself I use

```
SKSpriteNode * MainMenuBackground;
MainMenuBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background1"];
```

so for the other devices can I do these filenames:

```
Background1@2x~iphone5.png (1334 x 750)
Background1@2x~iphone6.png (1136 x 640)
Background1@3x~iphone6plus.png (2208x1242)
Background1~ipad.png (1024x768)
Background1@2x~ipadRetina.png(2048x1536)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721291/sprite-kit-art-assets-naming-convention/26722225#26722225